# Opera Developer gets wrong (red) icon when launched from terminal

Tags: icons, opera

I have Opera Developer installed in Ubuntu 14.04

When I start Opera-developer from the dash it starts and has a blue icon in the Application but when start Opera from the terminal (for example with some extra CLI switches) it gets the Red icon of the old Opera Presto, which is confusing.

Also when I start Opera Developer from the Launcher submenu with a right click `New Private Window` it gives me the red icon.

How can I fix that?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To get the Opera Developer **blue** icon working:

Rename:

```
/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/opera
```

to

```
/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/opera-developer
```

And update the link `usr/bin/opera-developer` to the new name:

```
../lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/opera-developer/opera-developer
```

This way Opera Developer will always get the blue icon, whether you launch it from the terminal or Unit launcher.